# Using string constants in implicit conversion

Tags: c#, string, operators, implicit, implicit-conversion

Consider the following code:

```
public class TextType {

    public TextType(String text) {
        underlyingString = text;
    }

    public static implicit operator String(TextType text) {
        return text.underlyingString;
    }

    private String underlyingString;
}

TextType text = new TextType("Something");
String str = text; // This is OK.
```

But I want to be able do the following, if possible.

```
TextType textFromStringConstant = "SomeOtherText";
```

I can't extend the String class with the TextType implicit operator overload, but is there any way to assign a literal string to another class (which is handled by a method or something)?

String is a reference type so when they developed C# they obviously had to use some way to get a string literal to the class. I just hope it's not hardcoded into the language.

Comment: See section 10.10.3 of the specification for details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public static implicit operator TextType(String text) {
    return new TextType(text);
}
```

Comment: Fix text != value - you were faster though :)

Comment: I can't believe how I missed that operator overloads goes both ways. I had a feeling the method would have to belong to the String class...
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
public static implicit operator TextType(string content) {
  return new TextType(content);
}
```

to your class? :)